# Why does Malus's Law contain a cosine-squared term instead of an absolute-value-of-cosine term?

Tags: optics, polarization

Malus's Law says that when polarized light of intensity $I_0$ passes through an ideal polarizing filter oriented at angle $θ_i$ with the light, the measured intensity $I$ of the light that passes through will be $I = I_0 \cos(θ_i)^2$. **Why is it cosine-squared instead of $I = I_0 |\cos(θ_i)|$ (absolute value of cosine)?**

My understanding of the way a polarizing filter works is that it absorbs the energy of a photon that is perpendicular to the direction of the filter, while transmitting the energy that is parallel with the direction of the filter. By my understanding, the energy that passes through would be proportional to the cosine function with the negative portions flipped to be above zero - in other words, the absolute value of the cosine function. But by the actual formulation of Malus's Law, noticeably less light than I expect makes it through the filter when it is more than a few degrees off of being parallel to the incoming light. Why is this?

My expectation:

[image: Graph of the absolute value of the cosine function.]

The reality according to everything I can find online:

[image: Graph of the cosine-squared function.]

The difference between my expectation and the reality:

[image: Graph of the difference between the previous two functions.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polarizer breaks the electric field into its vector components parallel to and perpendicular to the polarizer axis.  The vector "projection operator" is $\cos\theta$.  However, the intensity of light is proportional to the square of the electric field.

Comment: So the difference between my expectation and the reality is that the polarizing filter is acting on the electrical energy, rather than the light energy, of the photons, so to speak?

Comment: Energy density in an electromagnetic field goes like $E^2+B^2$, but an electromagnetic wave has a constant ratio between $E$ and $B$. So you can choose one or the other when computing the energy.  Note that if you *split* the polarizations, rather than absorbing one, you need intensity proportional to field-squared in order to conserve energy.